# Understanding generally how emails are received / sent (dns records)

Tags: email, cloud-computing, g-suite, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

So I registered a domain name through google, and I'm going to set up a small server through rackspace's cloud servers.

I'd prefer to keep my email going to google apps, rather than have to have my cloud server handle the mail.

There's a line in my domain services section that has this:

host: mail
address: ghs.google.com.
record type: cname

Do I just leave that line in?

So does email just get sent to mail.example.com? I mean generally speaking if I sent an email to john@smith.com, does it really just send it to john@mail.smith.com? Or am I confused or something.

Also, how could this potentially affect sending mail from the cloud server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should let Google handle the mail reception / sending if your cloud should not take care of it.

The `MX` DNS type is specific to mail and conveniently indicates (with priorities) which server will actually handle mail reception for a given domain. Thus avoiding the need to specify a mail server / subdomain. But it may work also without the `mail.` prefix, if the `mail.smith.com` host has a valid IP address and accepts mail for that domain.

But usually `MX` entries are created in DNS to specify that `mail.smith.com` will handle the mail for the `smith.com` domain. It makes things easier.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)